# Can't get NSKeyedArchiver to work: unrecognized selector

Tags: swift, nskeyedarchiver

In a `UITableView` when deleting a row and saving the data source I also want to save to persistent storage.

I'm using `NSKeyedArchiver` to save an array of my custom object type `Participant` and it fails straight away with:

> 2018-02-13 23:01:41.818945+0000 ProjectName[28680:5720571]
>   -[_SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800004d290
>
> 2018-02-13 23:01:41.826553+0000 ProjectName[28680:5720571] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue
>   encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x60800004d290'

I've searched everywhere and can't find anything that's applicable to me. So far as I can tell my data class for `Participant` object conforms to `NSObject` and `NSCoding` with the necessary methods implemented.

**EDIT**: Thank you all for your feedback so quickly. Code is below and as I said before, if I've neglected to post something necessary that likely speaks to my experience so any help gratefully received!

**Data Class (excerpt)**

```
class Participant: NSObject, NSCoding {

    //MARK: Properties
    var name: String
    var jobTitle: String?
    var picture: UIImage?
    var rate: Float
    var ratePeriod: ratePeriods

   //MARK: Archiving Paths

    static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("participants")

    //MARK: Types

    struct PropertyKey {
        //THESE MUST NOT CHANGE ONCE BUILT
        static let name = "name"
        static let jobTitle = "jobTitle"
        static let picture = "picture"
        static let rate = "rate"
        static let ratePeriod = "ratePeriod"
    }

    //MARK: Initialisation

    init?(name: String, jobTitle: String?, picture: UIImage?, rate: Float?, ratePeriod: ratePeriods?) {

        //The name must not be empty
        guard !name.isEmpty else {
            return nil
        }

        //Init stored properties
        self.name = name
        self.jobTitle = jobTitle ?? ""
        self.picture = picture
        self.rate = rate ?? 0.0
        self.ratePeriod = ratePeriod ?? .annually
    }

    //MARK: NSCoding
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(name, forKey: PropertyKey.name)
        aCoder.encode(jobTitle, forKey: PropertyKey.jobTitle)
        aCoder.encode(picture, forKey: PropertyKey.picture)
        aCoder.encode(rate, forKey: PropertyKey.rate)
        aCoder.encode(ratePeriod, forKey: PropertyKey.ratePeriod)
    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        //The name is required. If we cannot decode a name string, the init should fail.
        guard let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.name) as? String else {
            return nil
        }

        let jobTitle = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.jobTitle) as? String
        let picture = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.picture) as? UIImage
        let rate = aDecoder.decodeFloat(forKey: PropertyKey.rate)
        let ratePeriod = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.ratePeriod) as? ratePeriods


        //Must call designated init
        self.init(name: name, jobTitle: jobTitle, picture: picture, rate: rate, ratePeriod: ratePeriod)
    }

}
```

**From inside Private Func where I'm trying to make use of it and it breaks**

```
   let archivePath = Participant.ArchiveURL.path
   let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(participants, toFile: archivePath)
```

Thank you again for any help I can get on this.

**EDIT 2**: I've done a bit more debugging and I guess my inexperience with the Xcode IDE and debugging has hindered this but it looks to be the `ratePeriod` property of the object being stored that's throwing the error. This property is a Struct which I think somebody else leaned to as being an issue. Is this resolvable or do I need to look at a different method for persisting storage of Structs?

**EDIT 3**: I've solved the problem but don't know how to mark this as resolved. The issue wasn't the Struct (which I wasn't storing) but rather an *Enum*. When using `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSCoding` to store Enums you need to store the `.rawValue` and reconstitute it as an Int. ie: -

**Encoding**

```
aCoder.encode(ratePeriod.rawValue, forKey: PropertyKey.ratePeriod)
```

and

**Decoding**

```
let ratePeriodIntValue = (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.ratePeriod) as? Int) ?? ratePeriods.annually.rawValue
let ratePeriod = ratePeriods(rawValue: ratePeriodIntValue)
```

Comment: Do you use Git? If so can you share the link so I can see the code?

Comment: I would venture to guess that you'll need to convert your objects to dictionaries for storage. But I need to see your code to know what's going on for certain.

Comment: @Jake If code that's necessary to answer the question isn't in the question, then it needs to be added _here_. Moving off-site means the post won't ever be useful to anyone else.

Comment: "So far as I can tell my data class for Participant object conforms to NSObject and NSCoding with the necessary methods implemented." But we don't believe you, and neither does the compiler as it seems.

Comment: Show your work or get prepared to have your topic closed.

Comment: Hi all - thank you for your points. I've added what I believe to be the relevant bits of code but if any are missing I'm happy to include them. Hopefully this can be taken off-hold and I look forward to your valuable insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very [simple article on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/) about how to make your custom classes `NSCoding`/`NSKeyedArchiver` compliant.  I recommend giving that a look.

As a basic answer, in order to make your object work with `NSKeyedArchiver` you need to tell the coder/decoder how to encode/decode your object.  For example, if this is your class:

```
class Participant {

    let name: String
    let id: String
    let age: Int

    init(name: String, id: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.age = age
    }

}
```

You would need to make the following modifications to make it work with NSKeyedArchiver.  First, declare that you are conforming to `NSObject` and `NSCoding` protocols.  Then implement the `encode` methods and the `convenience init?(coder:_)` initializer:

```
class Participant: NSObject, NSCoding {

    let name: String
    let id: String
    let age: Int

    init(name: String, id: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.age = age
    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        guard let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String,
            let id = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "id") as? String,
            let age = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "age") as? Int else { return nil }

        self.init(name: name, id: id, age: age)
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(self.name, forKey: "name")
        aCoder.encode(self.id, forKey: "id")
        aCoder.encode(self.age, forKey: "age")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your custom object type, Participant, needs to be a class (not a struct), and in particular it must be a subclass of NSObject. Now you can adopt NSCoding successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding @objc to your swift equivalent encodeWithCoder: method.  Ditto for the decode init method.  I doubt it's the solution but might be.

Also, please show how you wrote the NSCoding methods in Swift.  Maybe they don't match up, given the inherent conversion between Swift and ObjC for how they are to be written?

```
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
```